# Convolution of different rectangle functions with shift.

Tags: integration, convolution

I have graphs of two rectangle functions given and need to calculate the convolution of them, but I am stuck as how to approach this:

[image: The two functions]

Comment: Start by writing the equation for the convolution. Performing the integral should be easy.

Comment: Let $f$ be the first function and $g$ be the second function. Then one has that
$$(f\ast g)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau)g(t-\tau)~d\tau=\int_0^1 2\cdot g(t-\tau)~d\tau.$$
Now separate the cases: Evaluate the integral when $t\leq 0$, $t\in [0,1]$, $t\in [1,2]$, $t\in [2,3]$ and $t\geq 3$.